# UIView layout behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am still pretty new with how layout behaves in Cocoa. Say I have a UIView with UIActivityIndicator and UILabel as its subviews. The UILabel frame is as big as the UIView and it has its textAlignment set to center. The text says "Loading xxx...", where xxx is a string that can change depending on context.

Now, how do I make it so that my UIActivityIndicator is always placed exactly to the left of the label no matter how long the text gets? Remember the text is center-aligned.

Plz let me know if you need more clarifications.

Comment: Will the generated string always be 3 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to implement this is to calculate the width of the text in you UILabel, and then use the results to position your UIActivityIndicator

```
// width & height of your activity indicator
CGFloat wai = 20, hai = 20;
CGSize textSize = [[label text] sizeWithFont:[label font]];
CGFloat w = textSize.width;
CGFloat ax = ((WIDTH_OF_THE_DISPLAY - w) / 2) - wai);
activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(ax, (HEIGHT_OF_DISPLAY- hai) /2, wai, hai);
```

Comment: Thanks @Armentage! So I assume if the text changes, I'll need to recalculate and reposition? I was wondering if there is a more automated way.

Comment: In UIKit, no. However, you can size the label "large" and center text in the label for a similar effect which at the very least won't make comically large frames.

Comment: @Yann, I am not getting you. How would that make the indicator stick to the left of the text?

Comment: Other UI toolkits come with "layout managers", that let you put a bunch of view's into your window, along with layout hints that can be used to automatically place and position your views based on the amount of space they seem to require (using code similar to what I used to calculate the width of your label's text).  StackPanels, Grids, UniformGrids, WrapPanels, etc.  WPF & Silverlight make heavy use of layout managers.